# Force strict RSpec DSL only

Tags: ruby, rspec

As a naive programmer, I have lived a while with this **huge** mistake in my tests:

```
it_behaves_like 'a Database' do
  def build_content
    # ...
  end
end
```

After some random errors and adding more tests using the shared spec, I realized such code was wrong since the very beginning and *eating away* some valuable tests. It should have always been:

```
it_behaves_like 'a Database' do
  before :all do
    def build_content
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

After this 'aha momment' took my knowledge of RSpec one step further and now wonder why anyone should ever write normal *ruby code* inside the RSpec DSL namespace, I really just want to know one thing:

How can I force strict RSpec DSL in my specs, making illegal any random ruby code (non RSpec) outside my begin/let/it blocks ?

For example, in my code above, the function **build_content()** is what I call random ruby code. The first time it was declared within the DSL namespace, where only RSpec functions should have been used.

Comment: "why write normal ruby code..." - because, you know, RSpec DSL **is** normal ruby code. :) So I have no idea how one would be able to tell the two apart. If you used minitest, you wouldn't have such confusions to begin with. :)

Comment: I know... but minitest has even more Ruby code! ;-P  The reason I use RSpec is its DSL. Even if in practice it is still Ruby code, I want to go all the way DSL in the areas where only DSL is expected.

Comment: So? Just don't write regular methods there. It's difficult to enforce this kind of policies in ruby. This is the only answer I have so far :)

Comment: Considering that normally DSLs are implemented with some type of eval, my hopes to enforce 'strict DSL' mode are quite low. Even so, I really love the design strategy of making obvious stupid things, fail in a clear and obvious way.